# Тлумачення рядка з "Катерини"

Tags: значення-слів

В Шевченковій "Катерині" є такі рядки:

> За Києвом, та за Дніпром,
>    Попід темним гаєм,
>    Ідуть шляхом чумаченьки,
>    Пугача співають.

Яке значення вислову "пугача співають"? В словнику пугач:

> ПУ́ГАЧ, а, чол. Хижий нічний птах ряду совоподібних, який живиться дрібними гризунами. Не показуй пугачеві дзеркала, бо він і сам знає, що гарний (Українські народні прислів'я та приказки, 1955, 173);
>
> ПУГА́Ч, а, чол. Іграшковий пістолет, що стріляє пробками або пістонами. Хлопці поквапливо роздягалися. Хто зовсім голий, хто в трусах, хто в сорочці й штанях, але всі з гвинтівками і пугачами кинулись за Віктором (Павло Автомонов, Коли розлучаються двоє, 1959, 9).

Можливо це назва пісні? Більше інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Йдеться про старовинну козацьку пісню **«Ой, сів пугач на могилі»** ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/dx_0ECn6DNQ)¹).

У статті Світлани Гайдук «До символіки образу сови в поезії Тараса Шевченка»  ([PDF](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?C21COM=2&I21DBN=UJRN&P21DBN=UJRN&IMAGE_FILE_DOWNLOAD=1&Image_file_name=PDF/spml_2011_16_18.pdf)) читаємо:

> Образ сови як зловісного птаха збережено у фольклорі та в літературі. До прикладу, в історичних козацьких піснях крик сови та пугача віщує
>   вселенську тугу за втраченим і безнадію.
>
> > *Ой сів пугач на могилі та й крикнув він: пугу!
> >
> >     Чи не дасть Біг козаченькам хоть тепер потугу!
> >
> >     Щодень ждемо, щоніч ждемо – поживи не маєм
> >
> >     Давно було! Хмельниченька уже не згадаєм*
> >     [5, с. 105].
>
> У поемі «Катерина» Т. Шевченка віднаходимо алюзію до чумацької пісні, записаної поетом 1864 року у Сквирському повіті, де простежуємо тотожний мотив:
>
> > *За Києвом, та за Дніпром,
> >
> >     Попід темним гаєм,
> >
> >     Ідуть шляхом чумаченьки,
> >
> >     Пугача співають*
> >     [10, с. 101] .
>
> Вплив народної поезії та символіки на творчість Т. Шевченка давно акцентовано у літературознавчих працях. Уважне прочитання творів поета дає підстави до висновку, що він був добре обізнаний і з міфологією, і з народною творчістю.
>
> Зооморфні образи поет вживає у тому самому значенні. Зокрема, **образ сови у Т. Шевченка, як і в міфології, – це символ сну і темряви**.

---

¹) Текст пісні, як у всіх інших народних пісень, часто мінявся, тому на відео слова не збігаються з тими, що у цитаті.